# Spring MVC 3.x Setting Global Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have internationalization module and application runs in two different modes. To change the mode, we need to restart the tomcat server. Mode 1 supports two languages and mode 2 supports 5 languages. The languages are stored in a `.json` file.

Every time the user hits `index.html`, in the `@RequestMapping` of this page, I check the application mode. And based on this application mode I read the correct `.json` file. Extract the list of languages and set that in the model and then I return the page to the client.

Problems with this approach is - every time I hit the index.html file, the application reads the file from disk. which is not only unnecessary but also time consuming and it rings annoying bell to my developer ego.

What I'd like to have instead is, when the application boots up, I know the application mode.

How can get the spring MVC to read the file in the beginning and store this data as long as server is running? Is it even possible?

If yes, can you let me know what parts of Spring MVC do I need to look into?

I read about `HandlerInterceptor` and `@ModelAttribute` but it merely states how can I insert the data in each request. However, what I really want to know is how the persist the data read from the file once.

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches could be tohave a bean, which impements `InitializingBean` and loads the file in 'afterPropertiesSet' method. It would also have a method to return the list of languages and it could be wired into all other bean which need it.
You could also do it in 'HandlerInterceptor', just have it implement `InitializingBean` and store the list in the class variable.

e.g.

```
public MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdaptor implements  InitializingBean {
   private List<String> languageList;

   @Override
   void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response,
                Object handler,
                ModelAndView modelAndView)
         throws Exception {

        //set list in the model
    } 

   @Override
   public void afterPropetiesSet() {
         languageList=...; //read file
   } 
}
```